# Why the DATETIME value that I send from C# is stored in SQL Server with a difference of one day/hours?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, sql-server-2014

you probably will tell me that there's another similar question like mine out there.
The only thread I found that was kinda the same was this:

[DateTime values read wrongly from Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25448317/datetime-values-read-wrongly-from-database)

The same thing is happening to me.

Our company manages a web application all over the state. We are in the "head quarter", where multiple application servers connects to one DB Server, that's running SQL SERVER 2014.

The users have to save the birthdate of students, e.g, **2008-10-03**. No hour is set, so, it's supposed to save 00:00:00.000. The application is written in C#, using EntityFramework for the DB Connection.

Not all of the records are saved wrongly, but others are saved like this: 2008-10-02 22:00:00.000. Two hours less, and, because of that, it's not the same day anymore.

The birthdate is a DateTime field. How can I make this thing work correctly? Should I use a datetimeoffset?

I appreciate your time and I really hope you can help me. Thanks!

**Edit**

The code where this happens, would be like this:

```
public saveData (DateTime birthdate, int studentId){
    using(Entities DB = new Entities()){
        student myStudent = findStudent(studentId);
        myStudent.birthDate = birthdate;
        DB.SaveChanges();            
    }
}
```

As I said, I'm using entityframework.

We have a *network department*, and they've granted us multiple virtual application servers, so I couldn't tell you what's the region of the machine, because we're not identifying which server is saving the information (maybe if we do so, that would help us).

It's a little embarrassing, but I don't have a lot of experience with DateTime considering all these aspects. How can I make sure that my datetimes are considered UTC/Zulu?

Thanks for the quick responses

Comment: `Two hours less,`, I think it is 22 hours more... Do you have code where DB updates are taking place ? Also, are you using Web services to communicate with the DB ? and are you passing `DateTime` to your web service, that could cause the difference due to Time zone changes.

Comment: Could be a timezone issue, what region is the machine having the problem set to ?

Comment: First, do not use a DateTime if all you want is DATE! Second, it sounds like you are experiencing time zone changes. Make sure all your datetime are considered UTC/Zulu TZ, and you shouldn't see any time (hourly) differences in your DateTime fields.

Comment: I have edited my post with some of the information you need to know :)

Comment: @Habib Oops! I meant to write 2008-10-03 in the example. I already edited that part

Comment: How exactly are you collecting the date from the web part of the application?  Is it just an ASP.Net textbox and you're parsing a string?  Are you using a date picker control of some type?  Do you go through JavaScript?  It's more likely that the time zone is being skewed on input parsing, rather than on save.  Try debugging your application and set a breakpoint to see the value before you save it to the db.  Also - UTC is not appropriate for birthdays and likely won't help here.

Answer (score 2):

Specify UTC when creating the DateTime so that all calculations are normalized no matter where (time zone) the machines might reside.

```
DateTime(year: 2008, month: 10, day: 3,
  hour: 0, minute: 0, second: 0,
  kind: DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

However, since this date probably originates from a user interface you are likely working with strings so you can parse the date with a DateTimeStyles flag.

With time `00:00:00Z` to force the UTC date

```
var utc = DateTime.Parse("2008-10-03T00:00:00Z", null,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
```

Without the time works as well

```
var utc = DateTime.Parse("2008-10-03", null,
    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal)
```

Now persist the UTC DateTime

```
saveData(utc, studentId)
```

Comment: The last example will actually *cause* the problem the OP is trying to resolve.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try this and will upload the results later to let everyone know.

Comment: @MattJohnson according to my tests the `AdjustToUniversal` accounts for this and sets the DateTimeKind. But yes, I'd rather be clear and specify the time + TZ.

Comment: Actually, I take back my first comment.  However, the result will still not be UTC.  See the description [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91hfhz89.aspx). That's probably good, as you wouldn't want a birthday to be treated as UTC anyway.